# Storing current page WP list table HTML data into a PHP variable

Tags: jquery, wp-list-table, parse

I am trying to store my render post table HTML data of just the table into a PHP variable after the table is completely loaded.

I've tried to store:

```
$table = new Custom_Table_Example_List_Table();
$tablehtml = $table->display();
```

But this returns an array, not the full rendered table.. (e.g `<table>...</table>`).

I have tried using JS  `var table = $(#tableid").html` and with `document.write` to fire, but keeps coming back as undefined. But if I tie it to a click action of a button, the HTML data shows fine.

It may seem as if I would need to capture the data AFTER the system knows that the table and jQuery is loaded fully.

Comment: To put the table HTML in a PHP variable, you can use *output buffering*. But you could also do something like `<div id="my-table-wrapper"><?php $table->display(); ?></div>` and use `jQuery( '#my-table-wrapper > table' )` to get the table element via JS. (WordPress doesn't add an `id` to the `table` tag)

Comment: Yes I've tested that. $table->display(); seems to be an array

Comment: Which "that"? Have you tried output buffering: `ob_start(); $table->display(); $tablehtml = ob_get_clean();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ah!

```
function callback($buffer) {
  // modify buffer here, and then return the updated code return $buffer;
}

function buffer_start() {
  ob_start("callback");
}

function buffer_end() {
  ob_end_flush();
}

add_action('wp_head', 'buffer_start');
add_action('wp_footer', 'buffer_end');
```